# Notification box doesn't go away in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, notify-osd

I just installed Xubuntu 13.10 on my MSI Wind netbook. I had no problems with the previous version 13.04, but the first thing I noticed with this latest version is that the brightness OSD stays on the screen and even if I use the hotkeys to brighten or dim my screen, nothing happens with my display. Furthermore, the volume controls in my taskbar don't work either and some weird things are happening in the settings app, like flickering sliding bars.

I found another post that says if you use the the code: `killall /user/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon` the notifications should work again. However, when I tried that command in my terminal, Xubuntu told me it found no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgraded to 13.10 myself on the same type of machine (at least an MSI Wind U100), and had the exact same problem. Tried all this `acpi_backlight=vendor/acpi_osi=Linux` grub stuff that I usually try when dealing with backlight issues but nothing worked.

Then I found another thread with at guy writing about his U100 with backlight issues which he fixed with a BIOS update. I must admit I think it's drastic since it worked fine in 13.04 (so I guess something changed in between kernel 3.8->3.11)... I however didn't want to spend a lot of time on this if it would work so I downloaded the newest BIOS from MSI (1.10G) and used unetbootin to create a FreeDOS USB stick. Booted this (in regular FreeDOS, no EMM386/HIMEM mode), updated BIOS, and badabing everything worked...

So I guess it's worth it if you dare the BIOS update.

This also cleared the notification and rather erratic video issues.